# Image frame saving from Video without losing resolution and quality

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I want to save the images extracted from the video without losing any information, resolution and quality. I have saved using OpenCV in four formats `png, bmp, jpg, tif` The code is as below

```
    file = "video.MP4"
    video = cv2.VideoCapture(file)    
    # Find OpenCV version
    (major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    
    # With webcam get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) does not work.
    # Let's see for ourselves.
    
    if int(major_ver)  < 3 :
        fps = video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print ("Frames per second using video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS): {0}".format(fps))
    else :
        fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        print ("Frames per second using video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) : {0}".format(fps))
    

    # Number of frames to capture
    num_frames = 120;
    
    
    print ("Capturing {0} frames".format(num_frames))

    # Start time
    start = time.time()
    
    data = []
    # Grab a few frames
    for i in range(0, num_frames) :
        ret, frame = video.read()
        data.append(frame)
    print("Shape",frame.shape)
    # End time
    end = time.time()

    # Time elapsed
    seconds = end - start
    print ("Time taken : {0} seconds".format(seconds))

    # Calculate frames per second
    fps  = num_frames / seconds;
    print ("Estimated frames per second : {0}".format(fps))

    for i,img in enumerate(data):
        fileName = 'Frames\img_'+ str(i) + '.tif'
        cv2.imwrite(fileName,img)
    # Release video
    video.release()
```

My Questions are

1. In which of the format (`png, bmp, jpg, tif`) I should save so that it should not lose the resolution and quality of video.
2. Just putting extension like `.tif` in `cv2.imwrite()` saves it to that particular format?
3. Which library is the best to save `OpenCV, scikit-image or Pillow`

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: 1) None of the formats will lose resolution. JPEG will lose you quality. BMP is generally a poor choice. Go with PNG. 2) Yes. 3) They'll all do a good, reasonably similar job.

Comment: Consider writing the images to disk as you go, rather than accumulating them needlessly in RAM and being a *"memory hog"*... no offence to pigs.

Comment: FFmpeg is also a good choice `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 thumb%04d.png -hide_banner`

Comment: also see python-ffmpeg at this link https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples

Comment: @mughees is FFmpeg better than openCV?

Comment: FFmges is very fast as compared to openCV

Answer (score 1):

well `.jpg` is a lossy format so you can loose some information. So it'd be better to use `.png` format to save the video frames. Because in this case you can also set the `IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION` level. In cv2 its value is from 0 to 9. A higher value means higher compression level and longer time. This value defaults to 1 in cv2 so you can set it to 0 if you don't want to compress it at all. A example code is as follow,

```py
# lets say you stored a single video frame in variable named 'frame' then
# save it as follows to avoid any compression or loss of information

png_compression_level = 0 # for no compression what so ever (means larger file size)
cv2.imwrite(dest_dir_path, frame,
           [int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION), png_compression_level])
```

you can then also verify if the stored image lost any information or not by using a pip package called `sewar`

```py
img = cv2.imread('read the frame you saved as iamge')
# then
from sewar.full_ref import rmse, psnr, uqi, ssim

print("RMSE: ", rmse(img, frame)) # 0 is ideal value
print("PSNR: ", psnr(img, frame)) # inf is ideal value
print("SSIM: ", ssim(img, frame)) # (1, 1) is ideal value
print("UQI: ", uqi(img, frame))   # 1 is the ideal value
```